# How to solve this seemingly quadratic inequality?

Tags: inequality

$$\frac{2x-4}{x}\geqslant7$$

What is the best way to solve this inequality? I've tried multiplying both sides by
$$x^2(\frac{2x-4}{x})\geqslant7x^2$$
It seems it worked, but I'm not sure if it is correct....... Is there a better solution?

Comment: Consider $2-\frac4x\ge7$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x>0$, it would be $2x-4\ge7x$ or $-4\ge5x$, which doesn't work; if $x<0$, it would be $2x-4\le7x$ or $-4\le5x$

Comment: This is not a quadratic inequality, but it is a *rational* inequality.

Comment: @MicahWindsor It is equivalent to a quadratic inequality, however.

Comment: @YiFan, I agree but that's only because he manipulated it and turned it into a quadratic inequality. The original inequality is rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2x-4}{x}\le 7\iff\frac{2x-4}{x}-7\le0\iff\frac{-5x-4}{x}\le0\stackrel{\cdot x^2}\iff-5x\left(x+\frac45\right)\le 0\iff\ldots$$

Try now to end the argument and find the solution.

The above is the general way to these inequalities: make one side zero as shown above and etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method as suggested in the comments: we can rewrite $$\frac{2x-4}{x}=2-\frac4x,$$ so the inequality we have is equivalent to $$2-\frac4x\geq7\iff\frac4x\leq-5.$$ For negative $x$, taking reciprocals, this is the same as $$\frac x4\geq-\frac15\iff x\geq-\frac45.$$
You can verify that the inequality is never satisfied for positive $x$ since $4/x$ would be greater than $0$. Hence, your final answer is $$\boxed{-\frac45\leq x<0.\,}$$